# GIT File Remains in History Even After Removed

Tags: git

I have a large file in git that was later removed. `file_123.xlsx`

I want to delete it from history as well due to its size, but can't seem to do so. I've followed instructions from many others that say the following:

```
git filter-branch --index-filter "git rm -r -rf --cached --ignore-unmatched file_123.xlsx" HEAD
```

Which shows the file getting removed

```
rm 'file_123.xlsx'
rewrite xxxxx (168/168)
Ref 'refs/heads/master' was rewritten
```

I then follow these steps for garbage collection

```
git reflog expire --expire=now --all
git gc --prune=now
git gc --aggressive --prune=now
```

However, when I go to my objects folder, I can still find the file in the pack. I do this first to list the blob ids that are large.

```
git verify-pack -v packxxx.idx | sort -k 3 -n | tail -3

123abc blob xxx xxx xxx
456abc blob xxx xxx xxx
789abc blob xxx xxx xxx
```

I then look at the last one on the list

```
git rev-list --objects --all | grep 789abc
```

This reveals the file I tried to delete:

```
789abcfile_123.xlsx
```

And my git folder has not gone down in size at all. Am I missing something, or is this file simply not getting deleted?

Answer (score 2):

Your filter command is `git filter-branch … HEAD` but your list command is `git rev-list … --all`. That is, you filtered one branch (`master`) but searched the file in all branches.

Filter all other branches too:

```
git filter-branch --index-filter "git rm -r -rf --cached --ignore-unmatched file_123.xlsx" -- --all
```